# Create Spark DataFrame. Can not infer schema for type

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Could someone help me solve this problem I have with Spark DataFrame?

When I do `myFloatRDD.toDF()` I get an error:

> TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: type 'float'

I don't understand why...

Example:

```
myFloatRdd = sc.parallelize([1.0,2.0,3.0])
df = myFloatRdd.toDF()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 149, accepted):

`SparkSession.createDataFrame`, which is used under the hood, requires an `RDD` / `list` of  `Row`/`tuple`/`list`/<s>`dict`</s>* or `pandas.DataFrame`, unless schema with `DataType` is provided. Try to convert float to tuple like this:

```
myFloatRdd.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF()
```

or even better:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

row = Row("val") # Or some other column name
myFloatRdd.map(row).toDF()
```

To create a `DataFrame` from a list of scalars you'll have to use `SparkSession.createDataFrame` directly and provide a schema***:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

df = spark.createDataFrame([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], FloatType())

df.show()

## +-----+
## |value|
## +-----+
## |  1.0|
## |  2.0|
## |  3.0|
## +-----+
```

but for a simple range it would be better to use `SparkSession.range`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark.range(1, 4).select(col("id").cast("double"))
```

---

* No longer supported.

** Spark SQL also provides a limited support for schema inference on Python objects exposing `__dict__`.

*** Supported only in Spark 2.0 or later.

Comment: I am a newbie to spark. can you please explain how does `myFloatRdd.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF()` resolve this problem? Does the `map(lambda x: (x,))` just convert the RDD object into a list of rows?

Comment: @kasa There is inference mapping for `tuples` (-> `struct`), there is no for scalars.

Comment: Using the very first option, one can provide col name in the same line: `rdd.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(['colName'])`

Answer (score 0):

###### Inferring the Schema Using Reflection

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
# spark - sparkSession
sc = spark.sparkContext

# Load a text file and convert each line to a Row.
orders = sc.textFile("/practicedata/orders")
#Split on delimiters
parts = orders.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
#Convert to Row
orders_struct = parts.map(lambda p: Row(order_id=int(p[0]), order_date=p[1], customer_id=p[2], order_status=p[3]))
for i in orders_struct.take(5): print(i)
#convert the RDD to DataFrame

orders_df = spark.createDataFrame(orders_struct)
```

###### Programmatically Specifying the Schema

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
# spark - sparkSession
sc = spark.sparkContext

# Load a text file and convert each line to a Row.
orders = sc.textFile("/practicedata/orders")
#Split on delimiters
parts = orders.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
#Convert to tuple
orders_struct = parts.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3].strip()))

#convert the RDD to DataFrame

orders_df = spark.createDataFrame(orders_struct)

# The schema is encoded in a string.
schemaString = "order_id order_date customer_id status"

fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schemaString.split()]
schema = Struct

ordersDf = spark.createDataFrame(orders_struct, schema)
```

Type(fields)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. If you think that you have something to add to the accepted `answer,` please state it clearly, and refrain from adding unexplained snippets of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, Row

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, None ]
l = map(lambda x : Row(x), mylist)
# notice the parens after the type name
df=spark.createDataFrame(l,["id"])
df.where(df.id.isNull() == False).show()
```

Basiclly, you need to init your int into Row(), then we can use the schema

Answer (score -1):

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
myFloatRdd.map(lambda x: Row(x)).toDF()
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer? Also, you should add an explanation