# PySpark: convert RDD[DenseVector] to dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have the following RDD:

rdd.take(5) gives me:

```
[DenseVector([9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432, 8.3397, 11.7699]),
 DenseVector([9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432, 8.3397, 11.7699]),
 DenseVector([5.0, 20.0, 0.3444, 0.3295, 54.3122, 4.0, 4.0, 9.0]),
 DenseVector([9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432, 8.3397, 11.7699]),
 DenseVector([9.2463, 2.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432, 8.3397, 11.7699])]
```

I would like to make it a data frame which should look like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| features                                                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| [9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432, 8.3397, 11.7699] |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| [9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432, 8.3397, 11.7699] |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------| 
| [5.0, 20.0, 0.3444, 0.3295, 54.3122, 4.0, 4.0, 9.0]             |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| [9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432, 8.3397, 11.7699] |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| [9.2463, 2.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432, 8.3397, 11.7699] |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Is this possible? I tried to use `df_new = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,['features'])` , but it didn't work. Does anyone have any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map to `tuples` first:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["features"])
```

Just keep in mind that as of Spark 2.0 there are two different `Vector` implementation an `ml` algorithms require `pyspark.ml.Vector`.

Comment: Thanks! map(lambda x: (x, )) looks very mysterious, would you please elaborate more? Thank you!

Comment: `(x, )` is a single element `tuple`. Mapping is required because only [some objects can be converted to `Row`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32742294/1560062)