# No FileSystem for scheme: s3 with pyspark

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark

I'm trying to read a txt file from S3 with Spark, but I'm getting thhis error:

```
No FileSystem for scheme: s3
```

This is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("first")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
data = sc.textFile("s3://"+AWS_ACCESS_KEY+":" + AWS_SECRET_KEY + "@/aaa/aaa/aaa.txt")

header = data.first()
```

This is the full traceback:

```
An error occurred while calling o25.partitions.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try `s3n://`?  Also, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754276/naive-install-of-pyspark-to-also-support-s3-access

Comment: I tried, but I still get the same error. At took a look at the question is the same thing I'm already using. Im using 2.2 pyspark

Comment: In Scala for access to S3 additional "hadoop-aws" libraries are required. Maybe, you need them too:  https://gist.github.com/eddies/f37d696567f15b33029277ee9084c4a0

Comment: I would suggest using some POSIX-compatible filesystem like http://juicefs.io that support s3 as a backend. You just need to mount the filesystem and then use it like a local directory, your code looks the same either in a local environment or some instance on cloud.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using a local machine you can use boto3:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
# get a handle on the bucket that holds your file
bucket = s3.Bucket('yourBucket')
# get a handle on the object you want (i.e. your file)
obj = bucket.Object(key='yourFile.extension')
# get the object
response = obj.get()
# read the contents of the file and split it into a list of lines
lines = response[u'Body'].read().split('\n')
```

(do not forget to setup your AWS S3 credentials).

Another clean solution if you are using an AWS Virtual Machine (EC2) would be [granting S3 permissions to your EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html) and launching pyspark with this command:

```
pyspark --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2
```

If you add other packages, make sure the format is: 'groupId:artifactId:version' and the packages are separated by commas.

If you are using pyspark from Jupyter Notebooks this will work:

```
import os
import pyspark
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2 pyspark-shell'
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
filePath = "s3a://yourBucket/yourFile.parquet"
df = sqlContext.read.parquet(filePath) # Parquet file read example
```

Comment: so boto3 doesn't work in cluster spark for some reason or what's the problem? I think I can wrap split boto command into DF, right? Otherwise I have same issue with spark 2.4.2 at moment

Comment: Just note this doesn't necessarily work, the version you load within pyspark script must be same as version in jars folder of your pyspark installation. My pyspark has in jars hadoo* files of 2.7.3, so I use it for submit args as well and now I can go simply with S3 (no a/n required)

Comment: Sorry, but why do you have spaces? Isn't the correct command `pyspark --packages=com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.7755,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.1` ? Note that this still fails for me with s3 and s3a urls.

Comment: It worked for me with the space between the arg name and arg value

Comment: Hi when I tried `pyspark --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2
` it gave me error `[NOT FOUND  ] junit#junit;4.11!junit.jar`, and the `No FileSystem for scheme: s3` error is still there, I'm using pyspark 2.4.4, any chance you know why?

Answer (score 14):

The above answers are correct regarding the need to specify *Hadoop <-> AWS dependencies*.

The answers do not include the newer versions of Spark, so I will post whatever worked for me, especially that it has changed as of `Spark 3.2.x` when spark upgraded to Hadoop 3.0.

### Spark 3.0.3

- `--packages`: `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.10.2,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.10.2`
- `--exclude-packages`: `com.google.guava:guava`

### Spark 3.2+

now it's released together with spark, so use the same version as your spark

- `--packages`: `org.apache.spark:spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12:3.2.0`

### According to *Spark documentation*

According to [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/cloud-integration.html#installation) you should use the `org.apache.spark:hadoop-cloud_2.12:<SPARK_VERSION>` library. The problem with this is that this library does not exist in the [central maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/hadoop-cloud_2.12/3.0.3).

### How to set extra dependencies?

#### in `spark-submit`

Use `--packages` and `--exclude-packages` parameters

#### in `SparkSession.builder`

Use `spark.jars.packages` and `spark.jars.excludes` spark configs

```
spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.10.2,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.10.2")
    .config("spark.jars.excludes", "com.google.guava:guava")
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

### `s3` vs `s3a`

The above adds the `S3AFileSystem` to spark's classpath. When you set this spark config not only `s3a://...` but also the `s3://...` paths will work:

- `spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl`: `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`

set is using `SparkSession.builder.config()` of via `--conf` when using `spark-submit`

Comment: thank you! if you're using delta tables, make spark context with extra packages like this: `from delta import configure_spark_with_delta_pip; builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp"); spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder, extra_packages=["org.apache.spark:spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12:3.3.0", ]).getOrCreate()`

Answer (score 8):

If you're using a jupyter notebook, you must two files to the class path for spark:

> /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/ENV-XXX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars

the two files are :

- hadoop-aws-2.10.1-amzn-0.jar
- aws-java-sdk-1.11.890.jar

Comment: if I don't use conda, where can I find these files?

Comment: Kindly show us how to do this

Answer (score 0):

There are pieces of this answer in each reply, the main thing you need is

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12:3.3.0")\
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")\
        .getOrCreate()
```

But you also need to put the `spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12` jar and its dependencies in your `SPARK_HOME`. Also check the dependencies of the `spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12` jar on maven central to ensure you're downloading the right versions. Adjust the below to your spark home, here it is `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark`

```
wget -P /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/jars/ https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12/3.3.0/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12-3.3.0.jar
wget -P /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/jars/ https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.1026/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar
wget -P /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/jars/ https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.3.2/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar
```