# Write Pyspark dataframe to S3

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Hello I am new to pyspark and I have a dataframe that I formed using the following method:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("input.csv")
```

I now want to write this df to s3 but I have tried everything available online with no help.

I first tried to set this up

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.access.key", "my access key")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.secret.key", "my secret key")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
```

But for this I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'hadoopConfiguration'
```

I also tried the following different methods to write:

```
df.write.option("header","true").csv("s3://mypath")
df.write.parquet("s3://mypath", mode="overwrite")
df.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').option("header", "false")\
.save("s3://mypath")
```

But for all these I get the same error:

```
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3
```

I am new to this and I really dont know what to do. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46740670/2129801)?

Comment: @werner I did but I get this error ```AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/home/ubuntu/Notebooks/s3/mypath ``` 
Why is it looking for path in ec2?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the configuration as :

```
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.access.key", "my access key")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.secret.key", "my secret key")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
```

Comment: Different error now ```AttributeError: 'JavaMember' object has no attribute 'set'```

Comment: which spark version you are using ?

Comment: spark version is 3.1.1

Comment: i will edit the configurations take a look jsut add  it the hadoopConfiguration()

Comment: can you please ellaborate on this answer? I cant understand (having ssame error)

Comment: do you still having the same error ?