# Read file data from aws s3 pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a json file placed in s3. The s3 url is similar to the below one:

```
https://s3-eu-region-1.amazonaws.com/dir-resources/sample.json
```

But in pyspark when pass the same, It is not reading the file.

```
path = "https://s3-eu-region-1.amazonaws.com/dir-resources/sample.json"
df=spark.read.json(path)
```

But I am able to download it through browser.

Comment: Did you added configuration for S3? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30852341/3945375

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `dir-resources` is the name of your bucket, you should be able to access to the file with the following URI:

`path = "s3://dir-resources/sample.json"`

In some cases, you may have to use the s3n protocol instead:

`path = "s3n://dir-resources/sample.json"`

Comment: Is region not relevant here?

Comment: In my case it isn't - I can access S3 files from pyspark with just the bucket name. Is this working for you?

Comment: no. I am getting the error `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.json.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:26`

Comment: Then it may be a problem with your local Spark installation. Have a look at this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851244/spark-read-file-from-s3-using-sc-textfile-s3n

Comment: Tried and installed. It didn't help