# createDataFrame() failing, can't figure out why

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a dataframe using what seems to be the canonical "hello world" of creating spark dataframes and cannot fathom why its failing. Help!

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([StructField("product", StringType(), True)])
l = [('foo')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.show()
```

Above code throws below error

```
ValueError: Unexpected tuple 'foo' with StructType`
```

The code is basically lifted straight out of [pyspark.sql module](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#) so i am completely stumped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Spark DataFrame. Can not infer schema for type: <type 'float'>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742004/create-spark-dataframe-can-not-infer-schema-for-type-type-float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because createDataFrame requires RDD[Row] as an argument:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.map (lambda x: Row(x)), schema)
```

Will give you correct DataFrame

Full code, tested Spark 1.6:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField("product", StringType(), True)])
l = [('foo')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.map (lambda x: Row(x)), schema)
df.show()
```

Comment: cool. I'm running in Jupyter so had to add `from pyspark.sql import Row` to make it work but that's perfect, thank you.