# Defining Schema for a large dataframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to load a large dataset from a txt file (1000 columns, > 1M Rows) into the spark environment and my dataset has no headers, as a concequence I have run into this error:

*TypeError: Can not infer schema for type:*

The challenge: looking at the examples given in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection), both examples show how to infer the schema using reflection and programmatically demonstrate the idea with few (two) columns that can be easily typed. No special column names are needed since the data represents a matrix.

How would I go about inferring from a larger set of columns, hopefully w/o typing out.  Or can the data be loaded in an alternative way that does not require these definitions.

PS: Spark newbie and using pyspark

EDITED (Added information)

```
dataset = "./data.txt"

conf = (SparkConf()
    .setAppName("myApp")
    .setMaster("host")
    .set("spark.cores.max", "15")
    .set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
    .set("spark.broadcast.compress", "true"))
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
.config(conf=SparkConf()) \
    .getOrCreate()

data = sc.textFile(dataset)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
```

data.txt contains 1Mn rows and 1000 columns similar to what would be obtained for example by the following code:

```
np.random.randint(20, size=(1000000, 1000))
```

Comment: You could start with providing example input (could be simplified, not need for 1000 columns) and the code you use to create `DataFrame`. In other words please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Updated by adding the code snippet. I have tried a couple of variants of getting a dataFrame but get the same error. Could you expound further how I could get around without the 1000 columns.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like you forgot about the  example data. At the moment all we can say is the exact source of failure is the same [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32742004), but it is unlikely to resolve your issue.

Comment: The example data is simply similar to generating a random matrix with 1000 columns and 1Mn rows.  I have come across closely similar discussions but not quite addressing the issue.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question - just imagine that someone asks you to write a code to parse an input but doesn't tell you how the input string looks like. Would you find this a reasonable task?