# Convert RDD to Dataframe in Spark Streaming Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to convert RDD to DataFrame in Spark Streaming. I am following below process.

```
socket_stream = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
def convert_to_df(rdd):
    schema = StructType([StructField("text", StringType(), True)])
    df =spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema = schema)
    df.show(10)

socket_stream.foreachRDD(convert_to_df)
```

I am providing input through socket `nc -lk 9999`

If I give "hello world" as my input it is showing me below error

```
StructType can not accept object 'hello world' in type <class 'str'>
```

expected output

```
+-------=-+
|text     |
+---------+
hello world
+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `RDD[str]` you should either provide a matching type. For an atomic value it is either a corresponding [`AtomicType`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/08c76b5d39127ae207d9d1fff99c2551e6ce2581/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L118-L120)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructField, StructType

rdd = sc.parallelize(["hello world"])
spark.createDataFrame(rdd, StringType())
```

or its string description:

```
spark.createDataFrame(rdd, "string")
```

If you want to use `StructType` [convert data to `tuples`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32742004/10465355) first:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("text", StringType(), True)])

spark.createDataFrame(rdd.map(lambda x: (x, )), schema)
```

Of course if you're going to just convert each batch to `DataFrame` it makes much more sense to use Structured Streaming all the way:

```
lines = (spark
    .readStream
    .format("socket")
    .option("host", "localhost")
    .option("port", 9999)
    .load())
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `ArrayType(StringType())`

Else since you have only one column try giving the schema directly as

```
df =spark.createDataFrame(rdd, StringType())
```

Check out udf for pyspark as you need to declare a udf for spark