# create a single column dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I've been trying to create a single-column data frame:

```
sasso = nyt.map(lambda x: (x.published_date[0][0]))
column = ["Time"]
dfFromRDD2 = spark.createDataFrame(sasso).toDF(column)
dfFromRDD2
```

any tips?

Comment: Add a comma : `(x.published_date[0][0],))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Spark DataFrame. Can not infer schema for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742004/create-spark-dataframe-can-not-infer-schema-for-type)

Answer (score 0):

was just missing a comma after the indexes.
Thanks zygD